# CSS: Align HTML canvas element to edge of screen

Tags: html, css

I am wondering how to align a canvas element to the edge of the screen.
It seems that by default, there is a small margin, as shown in the image.

[image]

I can set this margin to 0 in the body via css

```
body {
   margin: 0;
}
```

However, this causes all elements, such as buttons and text, to have that margin of zero.
If I try something like:

```
canvas {
   margin: 0;
}
```

This doesn't do anything at all.
I have also tried putting a div around the canvas element, but with no results.

Any solutions?

Comment: You should really set the body margin to 0 and style the other elements to give you the margin you want because you'll no doubt end up in a world of pain. However a rough-and-ready workaround is to set the canvas margin-inline to -8px;

Comment: Alright thanks, I thought of doing that but I wanted to know if there was a more direct solution

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the margin is on the document, try to style `:root` with `margin: 0;` as well.

See example:

```js
const cvs = document.getElementById("cvs");
const ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");

ctx.fillStyle = "#26292a";
ctx.ellipse(30, 30, 60, 60, 0, 0, Math.PI * 2)
ctx.fill();
```

```css
:root, body { 
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="cvs"></canvas>
```

Comment: Styling the root will have no effect. The margin is not styled on the :root or html element.  Its styled on the body on the user agent stylesheet. If you scroll to the body rule, you can see the margin is set there: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/+/master/Source/core/css/html.css

Comment: If the margin is set on the body just set the margin directly on the body element with the important tag. `<body style="margin: 0 !important">` This overrules anything coming from stylesheets